# Handle "Don't keep Activities" in android app

Tags: android, android-activity, crash

I have **2 activities**: an **activity** showing a list of informations to the user, and its **subactivity** where the user can create new informations.

In clear, from the first activity, I call a "**startActivityForResult**()" and when the user puts what he wants in the second activity, I go back to the first activity and I receive the informations in the "**onActivityResult**()" function to save the informations.

My problem here is the **"Don't keep Activities"** options. I read that this occurs in low memory phones. But how can we handle that when the device close the activities?

In my example, **when the second activity is called, the first one is killed**, so a crash occurs when we go back to that activity, and my informations are lost.

What is the proper way to handle that? Knowing that I cannot save my information in the second activity because I am using files.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState() method be called before onStop(). Hence persist the object there and retreive it back by checking if(saveInstanceState != null){ // get it back.}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to your purpose. By the way, you can use this technique to store your data when you close your activity at all.

Take your class data, convert it to String by using `GSON` and store it.

On load just move it from `SharedPreferences` and convert back from String to your Object.

lets say you have `MyData` class with all impotent information.

```
MyData myData = ....;

SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String toStore = gson.toJson(myData);


SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("stored", toStore);
editor.commit();

 ....
```

When you load back your previous Activity:

```
String loadedMyDataStr = mPrefs.getString("stored", "");
MyData data = gson.fromGson(loadedMyDataStr, MyData.class );
```

Comment: I am thanking you for your answer. I will try this code because I cannot find any other solution. But I have a question about the use of the startActivityForResult : if we want to prevent from the "Don't keep activities" we should never use a startActivityForResult and sending result with a bundle and the intent right? So where to use this function if we have error by using it?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, each activity can be killed anytime after the `onPause` method call. You can store your ListView state from the first activity in `onPause` and load it in `onResume` - you may use a singleton for this purpose.

Also your operations in `onPause` should be as fast as possible, don't do any complex operations in there. Otherwise your application may look like it has frozen and no user can interact with it...